# How do I conditionally format duplicates in each column in my worksheet separately ie. not between columns (columns A - NB)?

Tags: excel, duplicates, format, conditional-statements

I would like to flag any duplicates within each column of my worksheet but not between columns. I have tried entering the rules separately but once people start using the sheet excel seems to get confused....and it starts flagging duplicates everywhere (I am not sure but I assume this is because users are copying and pasting between cells)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post example data and the conditional format rules you've tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.